# How to change points individually in plot with for loop having if() inside? R

Tags: r

I have to make color of the points in the plot red if value of "y" is below zero, otherwise green. But like this all the points get the same color. I've tried the following:

```
x <- c(rnorm(100))
y <- c(rnorm(100))

x <- sort(x, decreasing = FALSE)
y <- sort(y, decreasing = FALSE)

plot(x,y)

for(i in y){if(i<0){points(x,y, col="red")} else {points(x,y, col="green")}}
```

but they are all green:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` to pass in the vector of colors (one for each point):

```
set.seed(1492) # makes the random number generation reproducible

x <- c(rnorm(100))
y <- c(rnorm(100))

x <- sort(x, decreasing = FALSE)
y <- sort(y, decreasing = FALSE)

plot(x, y, col=ifelse(y<0, "red", "green"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No loop necessary here. For better organization , put all the data in one data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(x,y) #Before or after sorting, doesn't matter
```

Make a colour column for each value of y:

```
dat$colour[dat$y<0]="red"
dat$colour[dat$y>0]="green"
```

Then plot your data as:

```
plot(y~x, col=colour, data=dat)
```

Or if you prefer:

```
plot(x=dat$x, y=dat$y, col=dat$colour)
```